# the matter of signal and slot of this program(Qt)?

Tags: c++, qt

I wanna link two pages that when the program runs and welcome page is shown after clicking "ok" next page comes.
here is my code but I don't know why it give error!!!!what is the problem?

welcome.h:

```
    #ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>

class welcome : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT


public:
    welcome(QWidget *parent = 0);
    QLabel *wel;
    QPushButton *ok;

public slots:
    void open();
};



#endif // WIDGET_H
```

welcome.cpp:

```
#include "welcome.h"
#include "login.h"

welcome::welcome(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    this->setWindowTitle("Welcome");
    this->resize(250,120);
    wel = new QLabel("Welcome to your program",this);
    wel->setGeometry(65,30,150,20);
    ok = new QPushButton("Ok",this);
    ok->setGeometry(95,70,60,23);
    login w;
    connect(this->ok,SIGNAL(clicked()),w,SLOT(open()));
}
void welcome :: open()
{
    login w;
    w.show();
}
```

login.h:

```
#ifndef LOGIN_H
#define LOGIN_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QCheckBox>
#include <QPushButton>

class login : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    login(QWidget *parent = 0);
    QLabel *user,*pass;
    QLineEdit *inuser,*inpass;
    QCheckBox *showpass;
    QPushButton *ok,*reg;
};



#endif // LOGIN_H
```

login.cpp:

```
#include "login.h"

login::login(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    this->setWindowTitle("Login");
    this->resize(300,150);
    user = new QLabel("insert your username :",this);
    user->setGeometry(10,20,120,20);
    pass = new QLabel("insert your password :",this);
    pass->setGeometry(10,50,120,20);
    inuser = new QLineEdit(this);
    inuser->setGeometry(130,20,150,20);
    inpass = new QLineEdit(this);
    inpass->setGeometry(130,50,150,20);
    showpass = new QCheckBox("show password",this);
    showpass->setGeometry(130,80,100,15);
    ok = new QPushButton("login",this);
    ok->setGeometry(125,110,50,25);
    reg = new QPushButton("register",this);
    reg->setGeometry(180,110,50,25);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my crystal ball is on repairs right now, so you'll have to tell us. What is the error?

Comment: no matching function for call to 'welcome :: connect(QPushButton*&,const char*,login&,const char*)'

Comment: well, you should place the connect on `this` as well ( as welcome holds the open function)

Comment: I changed the connect line in this way:"connect(ok,SIGNAL(clicked()),&w,SLOT(open()));"no error is given but when I click on "ok" button nothig happens???the slot is not recognized!why?

Comment: @Casillass Real: Najzero meant `connect(ok,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(open()));`

Comment: I add a private member to welcome class:"login *w"to use it in open() function"w->show()"now it gives an error that"login does not name a type"!!!why?although I represented login class!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`connect` expects a pointer (to a `QObject`) not an object, which is why you're seeing the error message you do.  The fact that you give `w` local storage duration is also fatal, as mentioned by Valeri Atamaniouk. You need to make `w` a member of `welcome` and declare it on the heap.  Note also the addition of the destructor:

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>

#include "login.h"

class welcome : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT


public:
    welcome(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~welcome();
    QLabel *wel;
    QPushButton *ok;

public slots:
    void open();

private:
   login* w;
};

#endif //WIDGET_H
```

welcome.cpp:

```
#include "welcome.h"

welcome::welcome(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent), w(new login)
{
    this->setWindowTitle("Welcome");
    this->resize(250,120);
    wel = new QLabel("Welcome to your program",this);
    wel->setGeometry(65,30,150,20);
    ok = new QPushButton("Ok",this);
    ok->setGeometry(95,70,60,23);
    connect(this->ok,SIGNAL(clicked()),w,SLOT(open()));
}
welcome::~welcome()
{
   delete w;
}
void welcome :: open()
{
    w->show();
}
```

Comment: @CasillassReal So what happened?

Comment: If QPushButton is only forward-declared, it won't work. Make sure #include <QPushButton> is there.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Editing make `welcome.h` complete along the lines of your concern.

Comment: @CasillassReal Also a slight concern with header guards, they should have the name of the class--be sure you don't have another `'h` file in your code somewhere that starts out `#ifndef WIDGET_H`.

Comment: @CasillassReal I edited the files since you last commented--have you tried that version?  You should only be getting this error if you didn't `#include "login.h"` in `welcome.h`

Answer (score 2):

You `w` is scope-local variable and removed right after you `connect` to it. Make it instance -specific.